# How do I make python run the current version of my code? Not a git problem

Tags: python

I keep getting the error listed below. The problem isn't that there's an error. It's that the segment of code that is throwing the error no longer exists. I modified it to address the error. It now calls a method .cooridnates() rather than the propery .extent, but it seems to keep running the old code some how (shown in bold). I tried swapping out my IDE and restarting the machine, but still nothing. It's not currently tracked in a repo. So I'm out of ideas. It's a windows 10 machine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\PGE_Pro_Py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\geometry\_types.py", line 183, in __getattr__
    return self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\PGE_Pro_Py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\geometry\_types.py", line 190, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, k)
KeyError: 'extent'
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \\rcnas01-smb\NRM_DataTeam\e_Scripts\~DS\Defensible_space_pre_inspection_form_export_2022_20211029.py, line 192, in <module>
    map_server_response = temp.site_map(item_webmap, 'Asset Centroid', "ASSET_NAME = '{}'".format(which_one))
  File \\rcnas01-smb\NRM_DataTeam\e_Scripts\template_fxn.py, line 154, in site_map
    **extent = sdf_zoomer.spatial.bbox.buffer(400).extent**
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\PGE_Pro_Py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\geometry\_types.py", line 186, in __getattr__

    "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (type(self).__name__, name)

AttributeError: 'Geometry' object has no attribute 'extent'
```

Comment: How exactly do you run the script?

Comment: I ran it in VScode, my primary editor. When that didn't work I ran it in IDLE. I got the same result both times.

Comment: try searching for *.pyc files and deleting them

Comment: I walked the directory from one level above all the way down and deleted all .pyc files. No Change.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the replies. I figured out the issue. Some how an old copy of the imported function library was saved in another directory that was also appended in. The program refenerced the first appended path with the old file first. So as I update the script the program continue to used the old copy.